# ¿Cómo desaparecer información de una tabla que ya está en otra?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en la cuál se registran los cursos a los cuales asiste el personal de una empresa. En dicha BD tengo dos tablas: `cursos obligatorios` y `cursos tomados`.

En la tabla de `cursos obligatorios` asigno cuales cursos son obligatorios para empleados de cierta área (ej. CALIDAD, PRODUCCIÓN, etc.), empleados específicos, o para todo el personal de la empresa.

En la tabla de `cursos tomados` simplemente se registra el empleado, el curso y las fechas.

El problema yace en que, cuando quiero mostrar los cursos obligatorios **pendientes** de un empleado, solo desaparecen los cursos que son obligatorios para **todo** el personal de la planta; cuando también debe desaparecer los cursos tanto si es por área o por empleados específico (Los cursos pendientes deben desaparecer una vez el curso ha sido tomado).

**He aquí la estructura de mis tablas (solo columnas que utilizo en el query)**

```
Cursos Tomados

 - cst_nume --> # de empleado
 - cst_cur --> código del curso

Cursos Obligatorios

 - cob_cur --> código del curso
 - cob_area --> área del empleado
 - cob_emp --> # de empleado
```

En el siguiente query (que es el que estoy usando actualmente) selecciono los cursos obligatorios pendientes de un empleado específico, ya sea por su código de empleado, su área, o bien si es general para todo el personal, siempre y cuando no existan dentro de la tabla de cursos tomados.

```
SELECT co.cob_cur, cu.cur_nom
FROM cursos cu INNER JOIN cursosoblig co ON co.cob_cur = cu.cur_cod
WHERE co.cob_emp = '$numemp' OR co.cob_area = '$area' OR co.cob_area = 'TODOS' AND co.cob_cur NOT IN(
     SELECT cst.cst_cur
     FROM cursostomados cst 
     WHERE cst.cst_nume = '$numemp' AND cst.cst_nume IS NOT NULL);
```

**Gracias por su atención =)**

Comment: Te van a interesar los triggers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html, lo mismo que los stored procedure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Sugiero que incluyas la tabla de empleados (importante que se vea como relacionas a un empleado con un área (puede ser un solo campo que tenga el texto del área o una tabla de áreas relacionada).  Lo sugiero porque es necesario para construir la solución.

También es buena idea que muestres unos pocos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas obtener con dichos datos.

Comment: @Cuauhtli podrias explicar que tienen que ver los triggers y los SP con este problema?